# Why isn't my UITableViewCell being casted?

Tags: objective-c, ios, casting

In my table view's `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I have

```
MenuItemCell *cell = (MenuItemCell *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ResultCell" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Before you tell me not to use a xib: I have more than one table view whose cells need to look identical. Using a xib seemed to be the best way to accomplish this.

The ResultCell xib in question is "owned" by `MenuItemCell`. `MenuItemCell` is a subclass of another subclass of `UITableViewCell`.

Here's the problem: I put a breakpoint *directly* after the cell allocation line, and here are my lldb results:

```
(lldb) po [cell class]
(id) $3 = 0x00b6b5fc UITableViewCell
```

Why is my cell a `UITableViewCell` and not a `MenuItemCell`? (Or maybe it is and `po` isn't the correct way to figure that out?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might not have told Xcode/Interface Builder to instantiate a MenuItemCell from the XIB, so it uses the default implementation, which is UITableViewCell. Note that casting an object only makes the compiler believe that it's an instance of the specified class; it does *not* magically transform the object into an instance of the class. (In other words, it's a copmile-time expression, not a runtime one.)

Comment: ResultCell.xib shows "MenuItemCell" in the Custom Class field of the Identity inspector when "File's Owner" is selected in the Document Outline. Does it have to show the same when the cell itself is selected in the Document outline?

Comment: Cool. And btw I don't use Xcode, so I don't know how to set those tricky properties (I always create everything from code, and anyways I'm not on Mac...)

Answer (score 1):

Here's screenshot on how to set the owner class of the NIB file

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can always check that an object is of a certain class with the isKindOfClass method.

[cell isKindOfClass:[MenuItemCell class]]

Also, like H2CO3 said. You probably forgot to set the owner class to MenuItemCell.